Superfluous space at start of aligned inside multlined
In the following LaTeX document, which uses the aligned environment inside multlined, there is an superfluous space after the opening { compared to when multlined is replaced by split:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \begin{multlined}
  %\begin{split}
    \begin{rcases}
      a_1\\
      a_2
    \end{rcases} = \\
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
      b_1\\
      b_2
    \end{aligned}\right\} x
  %\end{split}
  \end{multlined}
\end{gather}
\end{document}

How can I remove the superfluous space?
I have seen similar questions, e.g. aligned in multlined produces superfluous space, but they are different, because there, the superfluous space is before the closing } instead.
Example with multlined:

Example with split:


I believe you've discovered another “feature” of multlined

it looks like a bug that aligned is picking up the nested settings (I think I have seen that before) but you can work around it by setting it outside the display

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\begin{aligned}b_1\\b_2\end{aligned}$}
\begin{gather}
\begin{multlined}
%\begin{split}
\begin{rcases}a_1\\
a_2\end{rcases} = \\
\left\{\usebox{0}\right\}x
%\end{split}
\end{multlined}
\end{gather}
\end{document}


Thanks for the quick reply, David. Since you consider the behavior a bug, would it make sense to open an issue on github? Or is this already being tracked?

yes if you open the issue (rather than me) you'll get notified if we ever get round to fixing it.  I guess on mathtools rather than amsmath github @usertcl

Okay, I have opened https://github.com/latex3/mathtools/issues/60

@usertcl yes, it mailed me, thanks:-)
